# Pandas calculations across rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas dataframe and I need to add a column with calculation with referencing to the previous row.

I would like to calculate bid of current row minus ask of the previous row.

Example:

```
df = [[10,100,99],[20,280,300],[30,680,700]   ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['strike_price', 'ask','bid']) 
df = df.set_index('strike_price')
```

Column will be empty for first line. In the next line there will be 300 -100, in the new one 700 - 280 ...

I have tried to used pandas diff function but I dont see it working correctly.

```
df.diff(axis=1,periods=1)
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: You are not so far, have a look at the `shift` method [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). You can shift a column (default 1 row) and then substract the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question needs more clarification, but if I'm not mistaken, you are looking for this-

```
df['bid']-df['ask'].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simpler to understand.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = [[10,100,99],[20,280,300],[30,680,700]   ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['strike_price', 'ask','bid']) 
df = df.set_index('strike_price')

new_bid = []
x = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    y = row['bid']
    new_bid.append(y-x)
    x = row['ask']

df['Final'] = new_bid 
print(df)
```

Here assuming the ask was 0 initially

```
              ask  bid  Final
strike_price                 
10            100   99     99
20            280  300    200
30            680  700    420
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which fulfils your requirement -

```
import pandas as pd 

df = [[10,100,99],[20,280,300],[30,680,700]   ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['strike_price', 'ask','bid']) 
df = df.set_index('strike_price')

df=df.assign(Derive=df.bid.sub(df.ask.shift(1)))
df['Derive'][10]=""
print(df)
```

Here is the output of this piece of code -

```
              ask  bid Derive
strike_price                 
10            100   99       
20            280  300    200
30            680  700    420
```